# How is it possible to count div class?

Tags: jquery

i have multiple div class user, how can i count numbers of div ?

```
<div class="user">test</div>
<div class="user">test2</div>
<div class="user">test3</div>
```

For instance i want to get in a var 3 .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Ask jQuery to find them, and look at how many it found:

```
var theCount = $(".user").length;
```

Or if you specifically only want **`div`s** with that class:

```
var theCount = $("div.user").length;
```

jQuery's [`$("selector")` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) finds elements matching the given CSS selector and returns a jQuery object containing the matching elements. The [`length` property](http://api.jquery.com/length/) tells you how many elements are in a jQuery object.

---

In any modern browser (including IE8 and up), it's trivial to do without jQuery as well:

```
var theCount = document.querySelectorAll(".user").length;
// or just divs:
var theCount = document.querySelectorAll("div.user").length;
```